# What is the purpose of concatenating object values in d3 data function?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to understand the purpose of line 84 of this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/ganezasan/dfe585847d65d0742ca7d0d1913d50e1/):

```
.data(data, (d) => d.day+':'+d.hour);
```

It seems to return a string for each array element, such that `{day:1, hour: 2, value: 16}`, would be returned as `"1:2"`.  However, I cannot see what the purpose of doing this provides to the rest of the example. It seems to be dead code.

Please flag if this should be moved to code review, or another stack exchange.

Comment: Have you tried deleting that call and seeing if the demo changes?

Comment: @Phrogz Good catch! In my answer I focused on explaining why it is *normally* done this way. However, re-reading the question, I noticed that I slightly missed the point...

Comment: @Phrogz Somehow reminds me of [*"D3 map function, confused about multiple functions passed in"*](/q/44135218).

Comment: @Phrogz, I did delete that line, and it "seemed" to behave the same way.

Answer (score 3):

To override D3's default mechanism of binding data by index, a *key function* can be passed as the second argument to [`selection.data([data[, key]])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data). From the docs:

> A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a string identifier for each datum and element.

For this to properly work the key function needs to return unique keys for each individual datum. Since in the example's data both properties `day` and `hour` are by itself not unique, you need to somehow create key values which unambiguously identify the data objects, hence the concatenation.

Comment: This is a sample I found online, that seems to behave correctly, what would be the result of ambiguous keys? would it increment the value at that element?